# CSS dropdown menu fading in improperly

Tags: css

Having a bit of a strange problem setting up a fade in drop down menu - here's my CSS for it:

```
.main-navigation li ul li { 
 opacity:0; 
 transition:opacity 0.3s linear; 
 -webkit-transition:opacity 0.3s linear; 
 -moz-transition:opacity 0.3s linear; 
 -o-transition:opacity 0.3s linear; 
}

.main-navigation li:hover > ul li { 
     opacity:1; 
}
```

And the HTML (as generated through WP):

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <h3 class="menu-toggle">Menu</h3>
            <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="Skip to content">Skip to content</a>
            <div class="menu-nav-container"><ul id="menu-nav" class="nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-10 current_page_item menu-item-23"></li>
<li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25"></li>
<li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-24">
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-48"></li>
    <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47"></li>
    <li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-69"></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-27">
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-66" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-66"></li>
    <li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65"></li>
    <li id="menu-item-64" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-64"></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-28">
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-63" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-63"></li>
    <li id="menu-item-62" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-62"></li>
    <li id="menu-item-61" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-61"></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>
```

The sublists fade in properly when you scroll over the list item, but the problem is this: they also fade in when you scroll over the area where they will be. I can't seem to solve it - anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your HTML? Or even better, make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the full CSS.

Comment: Sure thing - I posted the relevant HTML, to the best of my knowledge. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements that have their opacity set to 0 still occupy space on the page (unless you position them or float them), and so when you hover on your sub nav, you are effectively hovering on the parent `<li>` causing the animation to run.

There's a trick using `visibility: hidden` and `position: absolute` to fix this.  As an added bonus, because the `visibility` property allows the use of transitions (`display` doesn't) you can make a smooth fade out effect as well as fade in by setting a delay.

I'd set the styles on your sub nav `<ul>` rather than the sub nav `<li>`s.

```
.main-navigation li ul { 
  position: absolute; /* Take it out of the document flow */
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.main-navigation li:hover > ul { 
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
  transition-delay:0s;
}
```

The visibility transition delay matches the length of the opacity transition length which means that when you stop hovering, the visibility won't happen until the opacity is finished animating.

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/vijov/4/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

```
.main-navigation li > ul {
 display:none;
}

.main-navigation li:hover > ul {
 display:initial;
}
```

Is probably what you are after.

Comment: Hi Pat,

Thanks for the help - that does stop it from activating when I mouse over where the new items will be, but it also gets rid of the fade entirely. Is it meant to replace something?